# picture source URL

Tags: photography

I would like to include 70 old photos in my book manuscript. It appears to be virtually impossible to find and pay all the copyright holders, if any. Is it infringement on copyright just to provide the URL to a picture instead of the picture itself?

Comment: Related: [When is linking to copyrighted material illegal?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/27025/when-is-linking-to-copyrighted-material-illegal)

Comment: If you only put a URL in your book, you're essentially saying "the information can be found here". You aren't actually copying anything. It is just a reference.

Comment: See also: [Is it infringement to give a link to a copyrighted file?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/4360/is-it-infringement-to-give-a-link-to-a-copyrighted-file)

Answer (score 1):

No. You are permitted to publish a URL.