# Is linking to a site that is hosting an illegal livestream (copyright infringing) legal or illegal?

Tags: copyright

Let's say there is this site that hosts illegal content. Would linking to it on my own website (USA Based) be illegal or legal?

The link would be up temporarily, then removed once the event has ended.

I've struggled to find a definitive answer to this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is linking to illegal free-movie streaming websites itself copyright infringement?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/65407/is-linking-to-illegal-free-movie-streaming-websites-itself-copyright-infringemen)

Comment: No, because the content I have in question is live sports, not something on demand like movies. Once the live sports event ends, the link is removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[united-states](/questions/tagged/united-states)

As a general rule, linking to a website (without hosting it within a frame at your own site) almost never gives rise to legal liability. See, e.g., [Perfect 10, Inc. v. Google, Inc](http://www.ca9.uscourts.gov/ca9/newopinions.nsf/DE8297F56287C0BC882572DC007DACC6/$file/0655405.pdf)., 508 F.3d 1146 (9th Cir. 2007). Similarly, [according to this source](https://www.dmlp.org/legal-guide/linking-copyrighted-materials): "No court has ever found that deep linking to another website constitutes copyright or trademark infringement."

The [same source](https://www.dmlp.org/legal-guide/linking-copyrighted-materials) cautions, however, that: "Contributory copyright infringement occurs by "intentionally inducing or encouraging direct infringement" of a copyrighted work. *Metro-Goldwyn-Mayer Studios, Inc. v. Grokster, Ltd*, 545 U.S. 913 (2005)." It goes on to explain that:

> Fred vonLohman gives the following rules of thumb to help avoid
> contributory copyright infringement (specifically with reference to
> embedding videos):"(1) don't embed videos that are obviously
> infringing, and (2) consider removing embedded videos once you've been
> notified by a copyright owner that they are infringing."
>
> Relatedly, you may be able to protect yourself against claims of
> contributory copyright infringement by complying with the
> notice-and-takedown procedures of the DMCA.

The exception to the rule would be when the link is an act in furtherance of a larger conspiracy in which the person posting the link plays a part.

For example, suppose that you enter into an SEO (search engine optimization) partnership with a firm that streams illegal child pornography on a pay per view or advertising revenue basis, and you agree to post links to the illegal site in exchange for money compensation as part of an overall plan to promote the illegal content. In that circumstance, you could have criminal and civil liability for the underlying illegal conduct as a co-conspirator with the operator of the site engaged in illegal streaming.

On the other hand, if you are a random third-party who, with no communication or coordinating with the website streaming the illegal content, who posts a link to its existence gratuitously, this would not give rise to civil or criminal liability.

It isn't entirely clear, however, that contributory copyright infringement needs to rise to the level of full on civil or criminal conspiracy to give rise to liability if you are well aware of the infringement, although there are basically no cases actually imposing liability in that very bare bones fact pattern.

Comment: Well Explained, and yes some precedents would be nice so I can save them if I ever need them. I have no connection with the website streaming illegal content, but I know that the illegal content is there.

Comment: And also the content is not something illegal like child pornography, it is live sports. So copyright comes into play, what does this entail?

Comment: @Hansen The same generally ideas come into play, but copyright law takes center stage with the caveat I metnion.